# Collaborative filtering when multiple items are rated multiple times by same user

Tags: collaborative-filtering

When trying to model as a recommendation problem the selection of an item that can be selected (and rated)  by the same user many times, I can't find references of previous work.
It could be a context aware recommender system where context might be the time point in which the item is selected but where for example User1 can select item A (and rate it) then item A again (and give it a different rate) and then again item A can be selected n times.. then the same for item B, but item A could be again selected at any time point, and that could happen for any of the A, B, C... Z items. Could this be modelled somehow as a recommender system?

Comment: Here is a decision to make, you can use the arithmetic average, or geometric average, or min or max or even the latest. It really depends of your business model and also of course your evaluation procedure. Nevetheless, your question doesn't belong on SO but rather on a datascience exchange.

Comment: You mean that I should take only one rating for each item and user? There is no way to reflect all of them? I would lose a lot of information if I do that

Comment: nope, and you can't even consider it as a multimodal recommender

Comment: OK thanks, I posted it in datascience exchange to try to find out how to model this, please any suggestion?

Comment: Try to ask it also on Quora. They like these kind of questions there :)